# Splitting a string with values to desired dataframe in scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a string with values say
"column1=1;column2=2;column3=3;column4=4" like that for say 10 columns
I want to find for example the value corresponding to say column2,column4,column6

How do I do that using Scala and Spark?

What I did till now is:

```
var df = Seq(("column1=a1;column2=a2;column3=a3;column4=a4;column5=a5;column6=a6;column7=a7;column8=a8;column9=a9;column10=a10")).toDF("custom")
val df2 = df.withColumn("temp_new", split(col("custom"), "\\;")).select(
     (0 until 10).map(i => col("temp_new").getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*
)
df2.show()
```

and I get an output as:
[image]

But what I really want is :

[image]

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just split it once again?

```
.map(i => split(col("temp_new").getItem(i), "=").getItem(1).as(s"col$i"))
```

Comment: And how do I assign the first part of the split as the column name?